# Problems with PlotRange

Tags: plotting, code-review, code-request

I have the following function:

$$f(x) = \frac{2\arctan(\sqrt{\omega^2 + 1} - \omega)}{1 + \frac{1}{2}\ln(1 + \omega^2) - \ln\omega}$$

And something strange happens when I am going to plot it with different PlotRange choice. Here is the plot according to the code

```
Plot[qbec[ω], {ω, 0, 3}, PlotRange -> Automatic]
```

[image]

And here is what happens when I plot it with the choice

```
Plot[qbec[ω], {ω, 0, 3}, PlotRange -> {0,2}]
```

[image]

P.s. Yes, in my case I called the function above as "qbec" because of some reason.

The fact is this: this function has to be plotted with three other functions together, and there is no problem in the final plot except for this "gap" or whatever it may be.

I NEED to choose a `PlotRange` of `{0,3}` because the plot needs to be clear, but when I do it, this function behaves bad. I already tried with `PlotRange`: `Full`, `All` and `Automatic`. No way to solve it.

Is there a trick or a way to fix it?

What I need is this function to start from $0$, as it shall.

Thank you!!

**EDIT - THE GAP**

Here is a zoom for the second plot, in order to make you to see what I mean with "gap".

[image]

**EDIT - qbec function**

```
qbec[ω_] := ArcTan[1/ω]/(1 + 1/2*Log[(1 + ω^2)/ω^2])
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So, as noticed the problem is that your function converges very slowly with `ω` approaching `0`.:

```
LogLinearPlot[qbec[1/t], {t, 1, 10^25}
  , Frame -> True
  , PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.05]
  , PlotRange -> {0, Automatic}
  , GridLines -> {None, {0}}
  , FrameLabel -> {"1/ω", "qbec[1/ω]"}
]
```

[image]

and is `Indeterminate` at `x=0`. So it may be tricky get that right automatically.

You can do this dirty trick though, just add a point at `{0,0}`:

```
Show[
    Plot[qbec[ω], {ω, 0., 3}
      , PlotRange -> {0, 2}
      , PlotStyle -> Thickness@.01
    ] /. Line[{pts__}] :> Line[{{0, 0}, pts}]
  , Plot[Sin[x] + 1, {x, 0, 3}
      , PlotStyle -> Red
    ]
]
```

`Show` and `Plot[Sin` are there to mimic your background case where you want to add more plots.

[image]

Comment: +1 More generally, `qbec[0] = qbec[0.] = Limit[qbec[w], w -> 0]` and `Line[{pts__}] :> Line[{{0, qbec[0]}, pts}]`

Answer (score 2):

```
ParametricPlot[{Exp[-x], qbec[Exp[-x]]}, {x, -Log[3], 300},
 PlotRange -> {{-.5, 3}, {0, 2}}, AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio, 
 PlotPoints -> 100, PlotStyle -> Red, AxesOrigin -> {-.5, 0}]
```

[image]

moved the axis just for illustration.